# Python function equivalent to R's `pretty()`?

Tags: python, r, pandas, numpy, scipy

I'm replicating some R code in Python.

I've tripped up on R's `pretty()`.

All I need is `pretty(x)`, where `x` is some numeric.

Roughly, the function "computes pretty breakpoints" as a sequence of several "round" values. I'm not sure there is a Python equivalent and I'm not having much luck with Google.

Edit: More specifically, this is the Description entry in he help page for `pretty`:

> Description: Compute a sequence of about n+1 equally spaced ‘round’ values which cover the range of the values in x. The values are chosen so that they are 1, 2 or 5 times a power of 10.

I looked into R's `pretty.default()` to see what exactly R is doing with the function but it eventually uses `.Internal()` -- which usually leads to dark R magic. I thought I'd ask around before diving in.

Does anyone know if Python has something equivalent to R's `pretty()`?

Comment: C-code: https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/appl/pretty.c

Comment: pandas has [cut](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) and numpy has [linspace](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) but unfortunately they don't produce rounded values.

Comment: @ayhan I actually think the closest thing might be in matplotlib's default tick-setting behavior on plots... haven't found anything close though.

Answer (score 12):

I thought that the psuedocode posted by Lewis Fogden looked familiar, and we indeed once coded that pseudocode in C++ for a plotting routine (to determine *pretty* axis labels). I quickly translated it to Python, not sure if this is similar to `pretty()` in R, but I hope it helps or is useful to anyone..

```
import numpy as np

def nicenumber(x, round):
    exp = np.floor(np.log10(x))
    f   = x / 10**exp

    if round:
        if f < 1.5:
            nf = 1.
        elif f < 3.:
            nf = 2.
        elif f < 7.:
            nf = 5.
        else:
            nf = 10.
    else:
        if f <= 1.:
            nf = 1.
        elif f <= 2.:
            nf = 2.
        elif f <= 5.:
            nf = 5.
        else:
            nf = 10.

    return nf * 10.**exp

def pretty(low, high, n):
    range = nicenumber(high - low, False)
    d     = nicenumber(range / (n-1), True)
    miny  = np.floor(low  / d) * d
    maxy  = np.ceil (high / d) * d
    return np.arange(miny, maxy+0.5*d, d)
```

This produces for example:

```
pretty(0.5, 2.56, 10)
pretty(0.5, 25.6, 10)
pretty(0.5, 256, 10 )
pretty(0.5, 2560, 10)
```

> [ 0.5  1.   1.5  2.   2.5  3. ]
>
> [ 0.   5.  10.  15.  20.  25.  30.]
>
> [   0.   50.  100.  150.  200.  250.  300.]
>
> [    0.   500.  1000.  1500.  2000.  2500.  3000.]

Answer (score 3):

It's not that elegant as in **R** but you still can use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
np.linspace(a,b,n,dtype=int)
```

where `a` is the beginning of the range, `b` is the end and `n` is the number of values, while the output type is `int`.

For example:

```
np.linspace(0,10,11,dtype=int)
```

> array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])

Of course if you want it to be more elegant you can wrap it:

```
pretty = lambda x: np.linspace(0,x,11,dtype=int)
pretty(10)
```

Comment: This works only if the endpoints are pretty...

Answer (score 1):

Here's some python code that does nearly the same thing as R, except for the cases where the range of `x` is zero or very small:

```
def pretty(x, n):
    """
    Returns a "pretty" set of bin boundaries roughly of size n
    that span x. Use, for instance, like:
      plt.hist(x, bins=pretty(x, 40))
    """
    # see https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/appl/pretty.c
    h = 1.5
    h5 = .5 + 1.5 * h
    lo = np.nanmin(x)
    up = np.nanmax(x)
    assert up > lo, "All values are the same."
    c = (up - lo) / n
    b = 10 ** np.floor(np.log10(c))
    m = [1, (2+h)/(1+h), (5+2*h5)/(1+h5), (10+5*h)/(1+h), 10]
    k = np.digitize(c/b, m)
    u = b * [1, 2, 5, 10][k-1]
    ns = np.floor(lo / u + 1e-10)
    nu = np.ceil(up / u - 1e-10)
    return np.arange(ns * u, (nu + 1) * u, u)
```

*Edit:* fixed an indexing error.

Answer (score 0):

What about numpy.arange?

```
import numpy as np

print np.arange(0,16,3)
```

> $ [ 0  3  6  9 12 15]