# Create bins of specific size between two values in numpy/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two values which define the maximum and minimum of a dataset (e.g. in the reproducible example below 2503 and 2991).

I would like to create a list of equal bin sizes (50) between zhe range of maximum and minimum value.

As a solution I am looking for a way to create a list `rangebins` which looks like this:

```
rangebins = [2500, 2550, 2600, 2650, 2700, 2750, 2800, 2850, 2900, 2950, 3000]
```

I have found the cut() function in pandas package which allows to categorize into bins, but does not allow to define the bin size.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

minimum = 2503
maximum = 2991
rangebins = pd.cut(np.array([minimum,maximum]),50)
```

Comment: rangebins  = [i for i in range (minimum,maximum,50)] #is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @adhg: almost. The result should look like this: `rangebins = [2500, 2550, 2600, 2650, 2700, 2750, 2800, 2850, 2900, 2950, 3000]`

Comment: Take a look at [bart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44396692/2285236).

Comment: ok, so for the first element in rangebins should always use floor to a number that is divisible by 50?

Comment: @adhg: Exactly this would be the case. Do you have e better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @ayhan and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44396692/3896548) I managed to do what I wanted using the pretty() function.

```
import numpy as np

minimum = 2503
maximum = 2991

def nicenumber(x, round):
    exp = np.floor(np.log10(x))
    f   = x / 10**exp

    if round:
        if f < 1.5:
            nf = 1.
        elif f < 3.:
            nf = 2.
        elif f < 7.:
            nf = 5.
        else:
            nf = 10.
    else:
        if f <= 1.:
            nf = 1.
        elif f <= 2.:
            nf = 2.
        elif f <= 5.:
            nf = 5.
        else:
            nf = 10.

    return nf * 10.**exp

def pretty(low, high, n):
    range = nicenumber(high - low, False)
    d     = nicenumber(range / (n-1), True)
    miny  = np.floor(low  / d) * d
    maxy  = np.ceil (high / d) * d
    return np.arange(miny, maxy+0.5*d, d)

binlist = pretty(minimum, maximum, (maximum-minimum)/50+2)
```